# How can i forcing current frame to be encoded as intra frame using libavcodec

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, libavcodec

I want to change gop dynamic to adapt to player. Smaller gop help for reduce first screen cost; Big gop help to reduce bitrate to save bandwidth.

I found nvenc has a function which can solve the problem above.
https://docs.nvidia.com/video-technologies/video-codec-sdk/nvenc-video-encoder-api-prog-guide/#forcing-current-frame-to-be-encoded-as-intra-frame

But I'm using ffmpeg. Is there any similar function in ffmpeg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `AVFrame->pict_type` is set to `AV_PICTURE_TYPE_I`, then the NVENC encoders, by default, will encode it as an intra frame. They also have a private option to force it as an IDR frame.

For the latter, add before opening the encoder.

```
av_opt_set(avctx->priv_data, "forced_idr", "1", 0);
```